# What is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $l^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

$\mathfrak{c}$ is cardinaity of real numbers. It is also called the **cardinality of continuum**. It makes sense to me that this cardinality is strictly bigger than cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. But what about relations to other cardinalities?

1. What is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R^n}$? Is it the same, because it is just "higher-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$, or is it $n$ times the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?
2. What is the cardinality of $l^2$ which is like "$\mathbb{R^{\infty}}$"?

Thank you for providing an answer and potentially a general approach to how to determine cardinalities of sets.

Comment: Do you know what it means to say two sets have the same cardinality?

Comment: After you learn what cardinality is (It is very basic i think) check Cantor-Schröder–Bernstein theorem

Comment: @Infinity_hunter I would say they have the same "size", but it doesn´t tell me so much about the sets.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I  suggest  you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_1:_|A|_=_|B|) to see the definition.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I edited, you are right, my formulation was not very bright.

Comment: Note that $|\mathbb R^n| = |\mathbb R|^n = 2^{\aleph_0 \cdot n} = 2^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb R|$. Also note that by choice for infinite $X,Y$, $|X \times Y| = \operatorname{max}(|X|,|Y|)$.